# How to setup a file association that uses DDE

Tags: windows, file, associations, explorer

I have an old compiler that I use as an editor.  If I launch a .cpp file from winfile (a version someone fixed to work with Win10), it is fine.

[screenshot of winfile associate properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGjXX.png)

This winfile is 32 bit and probably uses the wow which is why it is different and that is understandable.

What I want to do is fix it in Windows explorer.  When I try to launch it with Windows explorer, it launches the application, but doesn't open the file.  I thought perhaps assoc/ftype were what needed to be used to fix the association, but another stack overflow question talks about them not being relevant for Win8 and newer.  I tried adding a "%1" on it, but then explorer opens it, but winfile opens it twice, presumably because it is doing the DDE method on top of the "%1".

If ftype/assoc are older and don't work (or do they if there is no user level override?), how can you setup an application similar to the dialog above to use the DDE commands?  I didn't see anything in ftype/assoc about those properties.

Per above, I tried adding "%1".